# Function that caches when it returns unevaluated

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, programming

How would you go about implementing a function that caches not the result but the fact that it didn't match a pattern? So that it doesn't waste time recomputing a complex time-consuming pattern condition every time it needs to evaluate the expression.

```
f[i_] := Module[{res}, 
   res /; (
      res = i^2(* some time consuming calculation *); 
      Print[i]; 
      res < 8)]
```

I'd like that if I run the following example I don't get two Print statements but only one.

```
f[20];f[20];
```

An ideal solution would provide a way to make the pattern matcher skip a particular definition if it previously found it didn't fit. However, I'm happy enough with a nice way to make MMA just "let the unevaluated expression be" without wasting time every time it reevaluates it only to find it returns unevaluated.

So far I'm thinking of

```
Module[{fMatch},
 fMatch[_] := True;
 f[i_] := Module[{res}, 
   res /; fMatch[i] && (
      res = i^2
      (* some time consuming calculation *);
      Print[i];
      fMatch[i] = res < 8)]
 ]
```

which seems to work I guess. You have better ideas, or think that needing this kind of construction is a sign of bad programming?

Comment: If you cache failures, is there any reason to not cache previously computed values as well?

Comment: @Leonid and Rojo I believe there is some built-in caching on conditions already.  See the doc page for [`Update`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Update.html).  I'd love to dig into this, but I need to run now.  Perhaps you already know how it works?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I used `Update` in my work a few times when it was absolutely necessary, and I even answered some question about it on MathGroup, in one of the threads:http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a864bf7059938c55. I believe however that the case at hand is somewhat different, at least as considered up to now.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow, I had never come into Update docs before and I hope I'm not bitten by a bug of the sort any time; I wouldn't know when to use it but after it bit me hard. Reading MathGroup threads now

Comment: @Leonid no reason not to cache results, just said it to stress what I was not trying to do, not what I was trying not to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution makes use of an undocumented symbol that, if returned by an iteration, makes the evaluator stop searching and return the function unevaluated (as far as my tests show): `` System`Private`$Localized ``

Say we have some slow condition that will match if the argument is greater than 8

```
longCheck[i_] := i > (Pause[2]; 8)
```

Now we do

```
ClearAll[f];
i : f[j_?longCheck] := i = 3 j
i : f[_] /; (i = System`Private`$Localized) := i

f[2] // AbsoluteTiming
f[9] // AbsoluteTiming
f[2] // AbsoluteTiming
f[9] // AbsoluteTiming
```

to get

> {2.0011145, f[2]}
>
> {2.0001144, 27}
>
> {0., f[2]}
>
> {0., 27}

Comment: I think it is worth to add a link to your post where the origin of this undocumented symbol is explained: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71886/280

Answer (score 11):

The following definition of `f` uses an auxiliary symbol to cache all results, whether they meet the required condition or not:

```
longCalculation[x_] := (Print["calculating value for ", x]; x)

Module[{cache}
, m:cache[x_] := m = longCalculation[x]
; f[x_] := Module[{r = cache[x]}, r /; r < 8]
]
```

Here is a sample use:

```
In[61]:= f /@ Mod[2Range[20], 10]
During evaluation of In[61]:= calculating value for 2
During evaluation of In[61]:= calculating value for 4
During evaluation of In[61]:= calculating value for 6
During evaluation of In[61]:= calculating value for 8
During evaluation of In[61]:= calculating value for 0
Out[61]= {2,4,6,f[8],0,2,4,6,f[8],0,2,4,6,f[8],0,2,4,6,f[8],0}
```

Comment: WReach, I notice that you have the Fanatic badge, yet you don't post all that often.  I hope you'll post more; in the past you have provided some of the most enlightening answers of all.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thanks for the encouragement.  Even though I scan the site daily, I can usually only post once a week or so.  By the time that rolls around, I find I have nothing to add to existing responses -- this site has a thriving and knowledgeable community.  Also, there is a good chance that everything I know is already posted here or on the old site :)

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest thing I've found is similar in spirit to what you are already doing. I set up a function validQ which checks whether a particular expression has been tested yet.  If it has, then it returns valid otherwise it checks whether it is valid according to your test.

I find the input validation using `PatternTest` preferable.

```
validQ[expr_] := With[{vQ = getValid[expr]}, If[Head[vQ] === getValid, True, vQ]]

f[i_?validQ] := 
 Module[{res}, res /; (res = i^2(*some time consuming calculation*);
    Print[i];
    getValid[i] = res < 8)]
```

Here is the result using 20  which should print only once and 1 which should print twice.

```
In[3]:= f[20]; f[20];

20

In[4]:= f[1];f[1];

1

1
```

**EDIT:** Note that this will slow down quite a lot if you are going to be testing a huge number of values since downvalues are created for each case.

Answer (score 3):

If you allow for the use of `Defer` you could use a form similar to this:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[i_] :=
  Module[{res},
    Print["body"];
    f[i] = Defer[f[i]];
    res = i^2;
    (f[i] = res) /; (Print["condition"]; res < 8)
  ]
```

I broke up your Condition test to be more like what I believe the actual use of `/;` inside RHS `Module` is likely to be.  I give one `Print` for the body operation(s) and another for the condition.

This starts by assuming that the condition is going to fail and setting `f[i] = Defer[f[i]]`.  Then, iif the condition passes, `f[i]` is again redefined to the return value.  If for some reason you do not want to cache the condition-pass value you could use `Unset` here: `(f[i] =.; res) /;`.

This is essentially equivalent to this:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[i_] :=
  Module[{res},
    Print["body"];
    res = i^2;
    res /; (Print["condition"]; res < 8)
  ]

a : f[i_] := a = Defer[a]
```