# How to leave function unevaluated programmatically?

Tags: programming, functions, conditional

Is it possible to write a function in such manner, that it can be either evaluated or left unevaluated?

This is a general question. Sample below is just a sample. No need to find solution for this sample. Need a general solution.

Hypothetical sample:

```
F[x_] := If[x>=0,
    Sqrt[x],
    Fail[]
];
```

So that it gives

```
F[4]
(* ==> 2 *)
```

But

```
F[-4]
(* ==> F[-4] *)
```

I.e. hypothetical function `Fail[]` stays for "drop evaluation and leave expression unevaluated".

I know I can use `Condition`

```
F[x_] := Sqrt[x] /; x >= 0
```

But I wish to do that in imperative programming way. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I don't understand why this is not working:

```
F[x_] := Block[{fail},
  (If[x >= 0,
     fail = False;
     Sqrt[x],
     fail = True
     ]) /; ! fail]
```

**UPDATE 1**

Manual has a good example

```
f[x_] := Module[{a}, a = Prime[10^x];
  (FactorInteger[a + 1]) /; a < 10^6]
```

which is checking internal variables, not arguments. But why my version above not works then?

Comment: so this won't do? `F[x_?Positive] := Sqrt[x]`

Comment: I want to place check in the body of the function

Comment: Not in declaration, not in pattern definition. In PROCEDURAL manner.

Comment: what about `F[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], Defer[F[x]]];`

Comment: @chris this works differently with `F[a]` (returns `If[a >= 0, Sqrt[a], F[a]]` but should return `F[a]`)

Comment: then `F[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], Defer[F[x]], Defer[F[x]]]`

Comment: @chris, ah that looks good; is this totally equivalent to `Condition`?

Comment: I have no idea. As I said I would suggest using `Condition` rather than `If` but since you wanted `If`

Comment: `Condition` has a disadvantage that in complex situations I need to do the job twice: once while checking if function is applicable and secondly when calculating it.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Could you provide a concise example of your case with double application?

Comment: There's the built-in `$Failed`, which you can use instead of your `Fail[]`.

Comment: @J.M. how to use `$Failed` for that purpose?

Comment: @jVincent example is above; I am writing my own algebra and my own simplification routines; I want all simplifications be in one routine; I don't want to spread it into numerous separate statements with various conditions and each condition with code repeating part of main routine

Comment: @SuzanCioc Your examples does not illustrate the "complex situation" you mention in your comment. You can perfectly well do everything you ask using condition. If you have other cases where condition will not work, you could include it in you example to show why condition is not suitable for you.

Comment: @jVincent I don't believe you will suddenly remember what you didn't remember yet if I provide more complex example. From my point of view the question is clear. Probably the answer is "impossible" and this is ok.

Comment: @SuzanCioc You don't seem to be comfortable in the English language. I will repeat, Your posted question can be fully solved with your own suggestion (Namely condition). Please post an example of the problem with that solution. I suspect there is no problem and that problems you face have different origins, or are simply due to your own misunderstanding of what constitutes imperative programming.

Comment: @jVincent my question is general and it was clearly stated in English. Of course I am not interested in writing my own `Sqrt` function defined for positive numbers.

Comment: @SuzanCioc I never suggested such. I feel like you are missing the points of my follow up questions to your question. If you have time I suggest visiting the chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica I would be happy to continue the discussion and help improve your question.

Comment: @jVincent so I am in chat :)

Comment: Your example fails because `RuleCondition` (which is internally called by condition) has `HoldFirst`. Look at the trace and you will understand.

Comment: I don't know why this has been down-voted three times.  This is a good question.  It may not have been asked in the best way but it would be hard to ask it better without first knowing the answer, IMHO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for comprehension!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your posted code does not work because some of the code you want to evaluate is given as an argument to `Condition` which holds its arguments, you could make it work by changing this

```
f[x_] := Block[{ans, success},
    ans = If[x >= 0, success = 1; Sqrt[x], success = 0];
    ans /; (success == 1)
    ]
```

Notice that the first line of code is process outside of Condition. It might be easier to see if you write it in expression form:

```
f[x_] := Block[{ans, success},
     ans = If[x >= 0, success = 1; Sqrt[x], success = 0];
     Condition[ans,success == 1]
     ]
```

Compare this with how your example would be in expression form:

```
 F[x_] := Block[{fail},
  Condition[If[x >= 0,fail = False;Sqrt[x],fail = True], ! fail]]
```

You should be able to tell the difference. In the working code the code that sets fail is evaluated before Condition is evaluated. In your code, Condition is evaluated first, which holds the evaluation of the code. This is because condition has Attributes `HoldAll`.

Comment: Sorry don't catch the difference between I wrote and you wrote?

Comment: You mean I pass entire answer to condition while you assigned it to a variable first?

Comment: Ok, this looks like a final and  sufficient solution I was looking for. It both uses condition and procedural. So I was wrong avoiding condition at all and people were wrong forcing condition in normal form.

Comment: @SuzanCioc I added a comparison. It's because `Condition[a=2,b]` only evaluates the `a=2` part if `b` is `True`. So the code you use to calculate `fail` has to be outside of `Condition`.

Comment: Even better `F1[x_] := (If[x >= 0, Return[Sqrt[x]]]; (Null /; False);)`

Comment: Here `(Null /; False);` construct is approximately `Fail[]` function Mathematica lacks. The difference that it can't work nested and should be at the end of procedure always

Comment: @Suzan, try `F1[x_] := Module[{tmp = If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], $Failed]}, tmp /; tmp =!= $Failed]`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. However, it requires the use of the undocumented `` System`Private`$Localized ``, which was (as far as I know) [first discovered by @Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/588/function-that-caches-when-it-returns-unevaluated). This symbol is most likely an internal implementation detail of the evaluator and, being located in a context that is obviously not meant for manipulation by the user, should be approached with caution.

It is, however, quite simple to use:

```
Clear[F1];
p : F1[x_] := (
  p = System`Private`$Localized;
  If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], p, p]
 );
```

We thus have a re-implementation of `Condition` in terms of `If`:

```
F1[2]
(* -> Sqrt[2] *)

F1[-2]
(* F1[-2] *)

F1[a]
(* F1[a] *)
```

Note that this result lacks the `HoldForm`/`Defer` wrappers one requires with other approaches.

Comment: This solution is not persistent. When `F1[2]` is executed twice, it produces $\sqrt{2}$ and `F1[2]`

Answer (score 6):

A great resource about such stuff is the  [Tutorial: Package Design](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/184/). Luckily, it was written by [Todd Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4783/todd-gayley) who is also a registered member of Mathematica.SE.

The important part can be found in section *Error Handling*

> If a more complex test of the input is required, you can put the Condition as the last statement in a Module:
>
> ```
> f[x_List] := Module[{result, test},
>                     some calculations here...
>                     test = true or false depending on calculations
>                     result /; test
>              ]
> ```
>
> If test is set to False, the Condition fails and Mathematica pretends that the match to f[x_List] never happened, moving on to try other rules for f. This is a little-known tidbit of Mathematica programming. Note that Condition must be the last statement in the Module (or Block or CompoundExpression) for it to work.

But this is only a small part of this fine material. For instance, to return an error message, which contains the unevaluated function call, he give the following implementation

```
Clear[f]
f[a_List] := something
p:HoldPattern[f[a_]] := holycow /; Message[f::list, HoldForm[p], 1]

f[1]
(* f::list: List expected at position 1 in f[1]. *)
```

This tutorial is definitely worth looking.

Comment: In searching for the Villegas-Gayley trick (again), I ran across this which I hadn't noticed before. I like the last example, but [`Literal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Literal.html) should be updated to `HoldPattern`.

Comment: @rcollyer yep, `Literal` is outdated for very long. I don't know why I used it back then. Next time, you can just change it without asking. I trust the system of SE ;-)

Comment: So do I, but I tend to shy away from changing things on long time users. More out of a courtesy, than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Using the 4th argument of `If` should do the trick

```
F[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], Defer[F[x]], Defer[F[x]]]

{F[2], F[-2],F[a]} 

(* {Sqrt[2],F[-2],F[a]}  *)
```

or may be

```
F[x_] := If[x >= 0, Sqrt[x], HoldForm[F[x]], HoldForm[F[x]]]
```

so that

```
F[a]/. a-> 2//ReleaseHold

(*  Sqrt[2] *)
```

The first form (using `Defer`) would work also with `F[a]/. a-> 2` but you would need to say evaluate it in place, see the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html)

Comment: This means that both solutions are incomplete since do not fully resemble `Condition` behavior.

Comment: @SuzanCioc In what way does chris' solution fail? Also I second jVincent's request from above, I have yet to see a reason why condition does not work for you.

Comment: @sebhofer I can't post hundreds lines of code here. But you can trust me that I currently use `Condition` and I dislike it's behavior.

Comment: @SuzanCioc That is all very well, but you won't get any help here by saying: "I don't like the behaviour of `Condition` so give me something I do like". If you want constructive input here, you need to pose a question which clearly describes the problems you are experiencing and what you eventually want to achieve. Your question, frankly, does not fulfill these criteria.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Also, replying to a possible answer by saying: "This does not do what I want" but not giving any reason why this is actually the case won't help either.

Comment: @sebhofer, I gave (1) a question, (2) an example and (3) any answer I was requested. People just don't believe me that `Condition` is not perfect. I don't know why and I don't know why is it unbelievable since everything is imperfect...

Comment: @sebhofer I want all simplifications be in one routine and don't want to do the job twice; aren't these a good reasons???

Comment: @SuzanCioc Oh well, apparently you are just not willing to see that people actually try to be helpful. Anyway, I will not continue to argue with you here anymore.

Comment: If people would like to be helpful they would not set minuses to me. People just don't know the answer and are trying to make me responsible for this.

Comment: @SuzanCioc The downvotes are not due to people not knowing the answer. Trust me on this, this site has some pretty intelligent people. The reason is that you posted a question that reads like this "I want a function that works like List, but I don't like List, so do it without List". You never fully explain why you dislike Condition or what effect it is you are trying to get rid of. Essentially you asked an incomplete question. If you write a small example where the behavior you dislike in Conditions shows up, then people will most likely remove downvotes and be able to provide help.

Comment: @jVincent I did explained what wrong with condition: (1) it requires double computation and (2) it is declarative. I need procedural solution. Of course people minus me because they don't like to accept they are wrong, I am familiar with this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and just assume that your problem is that you are nesting conditionals inside your code definitions, and that deeper levels are ignored. If that is the case, what you could do is to use a conditional check to see if your code processed without throwing exceptions, and use exceptions as your `Fail[]` function.

```
mysquare[x_] :=
 Module[{n = Catch[

   (*Your code goes here*)
    If[x < 0, Throw[stop]];
    a=Sqrt[x];
    If[x == 7, Throw[stop]];
    a    
    ]},
  n /; ! (n === stop)
 ]
```

The you can halt the computation at different locations along the code and let it stay in an unevaluated form:
`mysquare[-2]` returns `mysquare[-2]`, `mysquare[4]` returns `2`, and `mysquare[7]` will evaluate `Sqrt[7]` but return `mysquare[7]`.

If this is close to what you are actually doing, I would suggest adding some tag to the objects you pass along, that signify that they where already evaluated and didn't change. Otherwise you will end up reassessing that they should remain unevaluated every time you pass them along. This problem can be seen for instance calling `Trace[mysquare[7] // Sin]` where the calculation needed to assert that mysquare should not evaluate will run twice.

**Update**

So just for kicks I tried to encapsulate this in a function, but since you need the condtional to wrap the code, I belive that it is not possible to keep a function only on the right hand side to carry this out (Someone correct me please if this can actually be done!). So what I did was create a function that transforms a function definition to include the Exception check condition:

```
 SetAttributes[noException, HoldAll]
   noException[f_[a_, b_]] /; (f === SetDelayed) := (SetDelayed[a, 
   Module[{n = Catch[b]}, n /; ! (n === stop)]])
```

Meaning you could carry out the above definition as:

```
  noException[mysquare[x_]:=(
     If[x < 0, Throw[stop]];
     a=Sqrt[x];
     If[x == 7, Throw[stop]];
     a
   )]
```

The parenthasis on the right hand of the definition is needed because of the way compound expressions is parsed, but can be omitted with a refined definition:

```
 noException2[
 CompoundExpression[f_[a_, b_], c__]] /; (f === SetDelayed) := 
  (SetDelayed[a, Module[{n = Catch[CompoundExpression[b, c]]}, n /; ! (n === stop)]])
```

Which corrects the error if you forget the parenthasis.

Comment: May be this sort of `Condition` may be used easier?

Comment: @SuzanCioc What do you mean?

Comment: You are still using a `Condition`, but in special form. May be it can be used easier, without throwing? See my update.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Note that the reason i use throw is to exit the computation as quickly as possible, if for instance you had a very intensive computation `If[x<0,a=42;success ==1];Pause[10];a` then using the example code you posted, you would always need to compute `Pause[10]`, even when you know early on that `success ==0`. Using exceptions allow you to short-circuit those cases.